# preg_replace_callback to prepend incrementing number

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

In a string I have following occurrences of substring (can be unique or repeating)

CX0001
CX0001
CX0001
CX0002
CX0003
CX0123

What I would want is that each occurrence of CX* gets prepended with an incrementing number from say 1200. So, the above becomes

1201 CX0001
1202 CX0001
1203 CX0001
1204 CX0002
1205 CX0003
1206 CX0123

The CX* strings is always a alphanumeric substring with 6 characters. One may or may not repeat across the entire string.

How can this be done using preg_replace_callback or is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Got this working as an example below:

```
<?php

$content = "this is some CX0001 to Check CX0001 and CX0001 or CX0002 CX0003 CX0003 for the CX0123 that we need CX0123 and CX0001 and see if the same works works";

$count = 1200;
function rep_count($matches) {
  global $count;
  return 'MARKER'.$count++.' '.'CX';
}

$content = preg_replace_callback('/CX/', 'rep_count', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```